# dataframe not reading float values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains times in float format for example 12.0, 12.25, 12.75 with 27 columns. I have an if which checks if a user-given time is in the dataframe, but it only recognizes the 12.0 formatted time out of the dataframe. I am checking from the dataframe df4 in a specific column "Timestamp" if the given time (return_time) is in the column and get the corresponding index so that I can change its value in each column and then write it into a csv file.

```
if return_time in df4["Timestamp"]: 
    idx=df4[df4["Timestamp"]==return_time].index.values
    df4.loc[idx,i]="CHARGING"
    df4.to_csv("test.csv")
```

I should have gotten 27 different times as a result to store them in each column of the csv but out of the 27 i only get a few that correspond to the .0 type. It doesn't recognize the other types like .25 .50 or .75

Comment: what's `i` here?

Comment: i is the column labels (it iterates for 27 times for the 27 columns each time)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the `values` of index that you want to select using `.loc[...]`. Just use `idx=df4[df4["Timestamp"]==return_time].index`